# Python caching attributes in object with __slots__

Tags: python, caching

I am trying to cache a computationally expensive property in a class defined with the `__slots__` attribute.

Any idea, how to store the cache for later use? Of course the usual way to store a dictionary in `instance._cache` would not work without `__dict__` being defined. For several reasons i do not want to add a `'_cache'` string to `__slots__`.

I was thinking whether this is one of the rare use cases for global. Any thoughts or examples on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic possible there - ou want to store a value, so you need a place to store your value.
You can't just decide "I won't have an extra entry on my `__slots__` because it is not elegant" - you don't need to call it `_cached`: 
give it whatever name you want, but these cached values are something you want to exist in each of the object's instances, and therefore you need an attribute.

You can cache in a global (module level) dictionary, in which the keys are `id(self)` - but that would be a major headache to keep synchronized when instances are deleted.  (The same thing is true for a class-level dictionary, with the further downside of it still be visible on the instance).

**TL;DR**: the "one and obvious way to do it"  is to have a shadow attribute, starting with "_" to keep the values you want cached, and declare these in `__slots__`.  (If you use a `_cached` dictionary per instance, you loose the main advantage from `__slots__`, that is exactly not needing one dictionary per instance).

Answer (score 2):

You don't quite need a global; you can store the cache as a class property and still define the expensive property as a `property`.

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    expensive_cache = {}

    @property
    def expensive(self):
        if self not in self.expensive_cache:
            self.expensive_cache[self] = self._compute_expensive()
        return self.expensive_cache[self]

    def _compute_expensive(self):
        print("Computing expensive property for {}".format(self))
        return 3

f = Foo()
g = Foo()
print(f.expensive)
print("===")
print(f.expensive)
print("===")
print(g.expensive)
```

If you run this code, you can see that `_compute_expensive` is run only once, the first time you access `expensive` for each distinct object.

```
$ python3 tmp.py
Computing expensive property for <__main__.Foo object at 0x102861188>
3
===
3
===
Computing expensive property for <__main__.Foo object at 0x1028611c8>
3
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the dict will keep a reference to `self`, preventing it from getting gc'ed.  You probably want to use a `WeakKeyDictionary`.

Comment: @shx2 Good point. I'm afraid I can't get this working at the moment, though (getting a TypeError when trying to add `self` to a `WeakKeyDictionary`), and don't have time to figure it out.

Comment: Either way -weak-key dictionary or not, there is no mechanism in there (but to writting a __del__ method) that would avoud these values leaking if these objects are destroyed.

Answer (score -2):

Something like Borg pattern can help.
You can alterate the status of your instance in the    `__init__` or   `__new__`     methods.